# Sort users by similarity in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL, I have a table of users, a table of items and a table of votes, the votes table has the votes that users have given to items. Not each user has voted on all items and a vote can be 1 or -1.

Given a user, is it possible to sort users by similarity in votes?

```
User Table        Item Table       Vote Table

Id | Username     Id | Item        Id | UserId | ItemId | Vote
-------------     ------------     ---------------------------
1  | Tom          1  | Apple       1  | 1      | 1      | -1
2  | Jenny        2  | Orange      2  | 1      | 2      | 1
3  | Jim          3  | Grape       3  | 1      | 4      | 1
                  4  | Lemon
                                   4  | 2      | 2      | 1  (Jenny voted the same as Tom)
                                   5  | 2      | 4      | -1

                                   6  | 3      | 1      | -1 (Jim voted the same as Tom)
                                   7  | 3      | 2      | -1
                                   8  | 3      | 4      | 1  (Jim voted the same as Tom)
```

In this case given userid 1 (Tom), userid 3 (Jim) is more similar to Tom because they voted the same twice, on itemid 1 (Apple) and itemid 4 (Lemon).  Userid 2 (Jenny) is less similar because they only voted the same once on itemid 2 (Orange).

In other words, Jim is more similar to Tom because he agrees with Tom by voting the same way as Tom twice, Jenny is less similar because she only voted the same way as Tom on one item.

Comment: what do you mean by ``similarity`` in votes? same vote values/number of votes are supposed to be similiar?

Comment: btw, in what language? php?

Comment: Can you give us sql structure ?

Comment: I was hoping to do it with a mysql call but I'm using PHP on the backend so I could use that too if needed.  I updated the question with the table structure.

Comment: It's still not clear what similar means. In your example where Jim is "more similar"... more similar than what? You need to define similarity better.

Comment: @WootWoot Note that the id column in your vote table appears to be redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry, what do you mean?  I need a unique id field in the votes table, right?

Comment: @WootWoot You need a PRIMARY KEY. You have one in shape of a composite key (UserId,ItemId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

```
SELECT all_users.userId, all_users.itemId, COUNT(user.userId) AS total_matches
FROM votes AS user
JOIN votes AS all_users
    ON all_users.vote = user.vote
    AND all_users.itemId = user.itemId
    AND all_users.userId != user.userId
    AND user.userId = 1
GROUP BY all_users.userId
ORDER BY total_matches DESC
```